# Incorrect-Reversed Backface Culling?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, culling

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

I have been trying to implement deferred rendering for 2 weeks. But all of the meshes in my test program are culled reversely. The code above should be the correct way to render a model. Every example i looked at draws the objects like that. But here is the result when i use GL_BACK as cull face:

[image: GL_BACK]

And this is the GL_FRONT:

[image]

GL_FRONT should have been the result i expected from GL_BACK. Strange thing is when I set glFrontFace to GL_CW, everything disappears. So this problem is not about winding. I spent all my day on searching information about this. Only thing i found is something about depth buffers. But I can't see any problems in creation. Just because of this problem, I can't correctly do stencil pass for spot light rendering. I enable GL_DEPTH_TEST in geometry pass. This is what i attach to my fbo as depth buffer

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthTexture);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthTexture);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthTexture);
```

The main question is, what are the possibilities that would cause a reversed backface culling ?

Comment: Your projection matrix would be a great help in determining why this is happening. Culling based on winding order is done _after_ projection, if you switch the handedness of your projection matrix for instance, you have to reverse the winding direction to compensate (among other things). Also, that is a wicked Depth + Stencil format, it's 64-bit if you were not aware (24-bits of unusable space) and not possible on older (pre-D3D10) hardware.

Comment: what is the usual, native depth+stencil format ? I actually dont have much info about it. As i said, changing front face completely make things disappear. Culling back gives the result that culling front should actually give. I create projection using glm::perspective with positive znear, zfar. I still can't see the problem :/

Comment: The most common depth+stencil format is 24-bit depth + 8-bit stencil. This packs into a nice 32-bit buffer. When you use a 32-bit depth buffer and 8-bit stencil, you wind up using twice the memory because the hardware/driver has to align everything to a power-of-two. It is not uncommon to use this format on D3D10 hardware, but you should be aware that it is considerably slower than you would expect because of the extra unusable storage requirement. Your choice of G-Buffer data formats is not relevant to this question, but I wanted to point out this performance/portability issue early on.

Comment: Too bad the problem is not about depth attachment :/

Comment: I had this problem because I thought I would be clever and use a z-up coordinate system by interchanging the y and z columns of the perspective matrix. Turns out this flips the handedness of the matrix. It also makes the textures backwards.